# For some reason when i add this to my code I get the unexpected end of file error. But I can't figure out what's wrong with this code

Tags: php, html, mysql

This is the code that's creates the error.

```
<div>
                <?php while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_comment)){?>  
        <div class="comment">
            <p><?php echo $row2['comment']?></p>
        </div>
        <?php}?>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here `<?php}?>`. You should use an space between php tags like `<?php } ?>`

For example if you write like `<?phpecho "Hello";?>` This is invalid. Because compiler will not found any starting tag like `<?php` Because it is `<?phpecho`. In your case it is `<?php}`